# Issue with a conditional in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working through "Python for Everybody" and I am having a hard time with an exercise. I found solutions online, but I'm more curious as to why mine doesn't work.

Exercise is:

```
Exercise 1: Rewrite your pay computation to give the employee 1.5times the hourly rate for hours worked above 40 hours.
Enter Hours: 45
Enter Rate: 10
Pay: 475.0
```

I tried:

```
hours = input('Enter hours: ')
rate = input('Enter rate: ')
qw = int(hours) - 40
pay = (int(hours) * int(rate)) +  ((int(qw) * int(rate)*1.5)
payy = (int(hours) * int(rate))

if int(hours) > 40:

    print(pay)

else: 
     print(int(payy))
```

and get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-13-423cdffdb7c6>", line 5
    payy = (int(hours) * int(rate))
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not understand how this is incorrect syntax. I also tried this earlier..

```
hours = input('Enter hours: ')
rate = input('Enter rate: ')



if int(hours) > 40:
    qw = int(hours) - 40
    pay = (int(hours) * int(rate)) +  ((int(qw) * int(rate)*1.5)
    print(pay)

else: 
     payy = (int(hours) * int(rate))
     print(int(payy))
```

.. and same error comes up, but this time print(pay) is the issue.

Ideas? Looking for explanation, not solution.

Comment: It's a typo in line: `pay = (int(hours) * int(rate)) +  ((int(qw) * int(rate)*1.5)`. You need to add a parenthesis in the end.

Comment: It's just a missing parenthesis. Your code is working great.

Comment: Sneaky parentheses...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have an invalid syntax on line 5:  missing the ")" at the end of the source code;
2. [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for math operations;